# Convert Image to PDF and send via Email in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I believe due to locker service these libraries are no longer working in Lightning component. 
`Verified in  : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console`
Is there any way to generate pdf out of image base64 data in lightning component.

Update:

How can I pass id dynamically while creating pdf using `renderAs` from Apex:

```
<apex:page id="testPage" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf"
           standardStylesheets="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" controller="TestCtrl">


    <img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!MyFileId}" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</apex:page>
```

I tried this, but I think as its a bing variable it did not work.

```
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.ContentType = 'image/png';
    attachment.Name = 'Test123.png';
    attachment.ParentId = 'CaseId';
    attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fetchBase64Image());
    insert attachment;
    attachmentId = attachment.Id;
    Page.ImageToPDF_ACE.getParameters().put('MyFileId', attachmentId);
```

So that I can make a fucture callout with that Id and use `page.getContents` to generate PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to convert image to PDF and send it from Lightning, or Visualforce or LWC:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Object fetchBase64Image2(){
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
    attachment.ContentType = 'image/png';
    attachment.Name = 'Test123.png';
    attachment.ParentId = 'CaseId';
    attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fetchBase64Image());
    insert attachment;
    attachmentId = attachment.Id;
    PageReference pageReference2 = new PageReference('/apex/ImageToPDF?FileId='+attachmentId);
    fetchContentDataFromPage(pageReference2.getUrl());
    return null;

}

@Future(Callout=true)
public static void fetchContentDataFromPage(String pageURL){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    attach.setContentType('application/pdf');
    attach.setFileName('Test.pdf');
    attach.setInline(false);
    attach.setBody(new PageReference(pageURL).getContent());
    email.setSubject('Test Email');
    List<String> lStrings = new List<String>();
    lStrings.add('Test@test.com');
    email.setToAddresses(lStrings);
    email.setPlainTextBody('Thank You .');
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[]{
            attach
    });
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{
            email
    });
}
```

`fetchBase64Image2`, this method can be invoked from Lightning, here you can pass the base64 version of image file, or base64 version of any file.

Inside that method I just created an attachment on Case. And added the attachmentId to the Param of the new page reference. In the new page have a `renderAs` tag as PDF. Which will render the image as PDF.

Next we are going to fire a future callout to fetch the page contents of the page reference we just created.

`fetchContentDataFromPage(pageReference2.getUrl());`

and finally send the image as pdf from future.

Here is the VF Page:

```
<apex:page id="testPage" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf"
           standardStylesheets="false"
           applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" controller="TestClass">


    <img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!$CurrentPage.parameters.FileId}" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</apex:page>
```